# Verb aspect is listed as being different or both

Tags: глаголы, вид

For the verb `живописать` (to describe vividly) [Wiktionary [en]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) lists it as imperfective; the [[ru] Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) lists it as perfective; while a database of verbs I has lists it as 'both'.

The database lists just under 600 verbs as having both aspects. The most common of these is `использовать`. This is listed as both imperfective and perfective on both Wiktionaries.

Can anyone offer insight into the aspect of `живописать`? And is there any reference on when a verb can be in either aspect? I cannot see any.

Comment: Yes, since there isn't a word like живописывать, живописать takes both aspects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *живописать* is a biaspectual verb, meaning its perfective and imperfective forms coincide.

Imperfective:

> И пока Рахатов живописал совсем не оригинальную эпопею, Женя думала о другом. // *[Ольга Новикова. Женский роман (1993)]*

Perfective:

> Фома рассказал, перемежая рассказ сдачей карт, подробно живописал тварей из здешних бассейнов, зал «эха». // *[Сергей Осипов. Страсти по Фоме. Книга третья. Книга Перемен (1998)]*

Comment: Is the imperfective or perfective nature implied by context?

Comment: @KohjahBreese: yes, and sometimes you can't tell it even from the context.

Answer (score 4):

From the book "The Iconostasis" (Иконостас) by P. A. Florenskiy (П. А. Флоренский):

- он питал внутри себя необоримое желание — **живописать** Деву Марию в небесном Ее совершенстве *(he nourished within himself an irresistible desire - **to paint** the Virgin Mary in Her heavenly perfection)* – imperfective
- и вот почему удалось ему **живописать** Матерь Божию в том образе, в каком он носил Ее в душе своей *(and that's why he was able **to paint** the Mother of God in the image in which he wore Her in his soul)* - perfective

Comment: The first example can also be read as perfective: желание (что сделать?) живописать. Сов. вид даже больше к месту, иначе получается, что он желал насладиться процессом живописания, а не результатом.

Comment: @SergeySlepov, ok, also there is another one: "наконец, он не мог удерживаться долее, трепетною рукою принялся **живописать** Мадонну"